# Change vlan settings to Yealink phones at once

Tags: ip, scripting, vlan, voip, phone

I have about 90 yealink ip phones. My target is to change vlan settings to all of them massively. For example, when it's going to reboot all of them, I run the following http:///cgi-bin/ConfigManApp.com?key=Reboot via a script with "for loop" for evry phone.

Now, I would like to change vlan settings for all phones at once and then reboot all these phones to make the change.
One way I thought of is to export the configuration file, make the changes, import it again and reboot the phone.

Does anyone have an idea how I could proceed with this and if it is effective something like that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend setting up an autoprovision server. You can use TFTP,FTP,HTTP or HTTPS with v6x and v7x firmware Yealink phones (maybe others too).

High level instruction on how to do it using DHCP boot provision and FTP file server:

1. Set up FTP server with a user and password (or not, but I would recommend it)
2. Set up DHCP server with boot option 66 (option boot-server 
   "ftp://user:pass@serveraddress/")
3. Edit your general and mac specific provision files (Auto Provision Manual says it all) and put it on the root your ftp server (simplest way)
4. Put your VLAN settings on the general config file if applying for all the phones, if not, put it on the mac specific file.

Example with vlan ID 290:

```
[ VLAN ]
path = /config/Network/Network.cfg
#ISVLAN,VID and USRPRIORITY are used for VLAN on LAN port
#PC_PORT_VLAN_ENABLE,PC_PORT_VID and PC_PORT_PRIORITY are used for PC port
ISVLAN = 1
VID = 290
USRPRIORITY = 0
PC_PORT_VLAN_ENABLE = 0
PC_PORT_VID = 
PC_PORT_PRIORITY = 0
```